# How to set Visibility function in flutter to show or hide Text Form Field?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, visibility

I want to set an option in my Trivia game to the user set a Text Field in specific question ID.
for now I trying to use Visibility widget but its only take the  bool _visibleText value,
And does not get the value from void validateText.
any idea what I missing?

this is my code:

```
class _QuestionCardState extends State<QuestionCard> {
  bool _visibleText = false;

  void validateText() => setState(() {
        if (widget.question.id == 1) {
          _visibleText = false;
        } else {
          if (widget.question.id == 2) {
            _visibleText = true;
          }
        }
      });
```

and the widget:

```
 Visibility(
        visible: (_visibleText),
        child: Container(
          width: 320.0,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: TextFormField(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide:
                    const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFCBA583), width: 2.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(12),
                ),
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
              hintText: widget.question.text,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16.0,
                color: Color(0xFF067751),
                fontFamily: 'Calibri',
                letterSpacing: 2,
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Solved by using this function:

```
  bool validateText() {
if (widget.question.id == 2) {
  return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to continuously toggle visibility during the game, please use `streambuilder` and leave your `validatetext` function inside `streambuilder's sink method`. Then `streamcontroller` will continuously change your UI dynamically.
If you don't understand at all, then please mention that , I will try to add the full codebase.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`validateText` is never called.

Change the function to this :

```
  bool validateText() {
    if (widget.question.id == 1) return false;
    if (widget.question.id == 2) return true;
  }
```

And in your `build` method :

```
visible: validateText(),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `validateText` function is never called. If you have a button that toggles this then call it in it's `onTap` event.